# Export Google sheet Chart as an image

Tags: google-apps-script

Would you please help on how to export a chart to a image using google script.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work. I'm worrying that the API **getAs** is deprecated.

```
function TestEmailCharts(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  if(charts.length!=0)
  {
  var chartBlobs=new Array(charts.length); 
  var emailBody="Charts<br>";
  var emailImages={};
  for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
    chartBlobs[i]= charts[i].getAs("image/jpeg").setName("chartBlob"+i);
    emailBody= emailBody + "<img src='cid:chart"+i+"'><br>";
    emailImages["chart"+i]= chartBlobs[i];
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email@gmail.com",
    subject: "test2",
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages:emailImages});
  }
}
```

To reproduce the problem,  create a Google spread sheet 
Create a simple chart with some data.

Add this code to scripts. 
Replace email@gmail.com with your email

Normally you should receive an email with chart image 
But the problem is that you will receive a email with black image.

Best regards.

Comment: I'd like to see more code.  And more explanation about what doesn't work.

Comment: Hello @SandyGood, I added full code & problem description.

Comment: I looks like a chart is structured as a **png** file.  If I manually save the chart as a file, it gets set as a png file.   The `.getAs("image/png")` conversion does NOT work.  It doesn't convert the chart correctly.  There is either something wrong, a bug, or there needs to be a new method to convert a chart to an image.  I can't find a way to convert it.  Maybe post the issue on the Apps Script Issue tracker.  Make sure to search first to see if something is already there.  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: Here is a Apps Script issue posting:  [Chart.getAs('image/jpeg').getBytes()](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3814&q=chart%20image&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

Comment: @AlanWells - were you able to find any alternatives to export chart as image instead of using this conversion? I ran into the same issue today - it says `We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again` 

Comment: Can you try this: `var charts = sheet.getCharts();var image = DriveApp.createFile(charts[0].asImage()).setName("chart.png");`  I have not tested this.  I just copied some code from somewhere else.  If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria, No unfortunatly at that time the proposed solutions were not working and I skipped the idea.

Answer (score 2):

*Exporting a Google sheet chart as an image*

**By Email:**
First create the chart and then get its blob. Then send the blob as attachment.

```
function createPieChart(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<ID>").getSheetByName("<SheetName>");
  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart() 
      .asPieChart() 
      .set3D()
      .addRange(sheet.getRange("A20").getDataRegion())
      .setPosition(16, 5, 0, 0)
      .setOption('title', "Total hour split in 2020");
  var blob = chartBuilder.build().getBlob();
  sendMail(blob);
}

function sendMail(img){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "john@domain.com",
    subject: "test",
    htmlBody: "fair enough",
    attachments: [img]}); //If this gives you problems, replace img with img.getAs(MimeType.JPEG)
}
```

**To another spreadsheet** (different from where the source data for the chart is):

Similar way, create the chart and then insert the blob as an image in the destination sheet:

```
function createPieChart(){
  var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<ID>").getSheetByName("<SheetName>"); 
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<ID>").getSheetByName("<SheetName>");       
   var chartBuilder = srcSheet.newChart() 
      .asPieChart() 
      .set3D()
      .addRange(sheet.getRange("A20").getDataRegion())
      .setPosition(16, 5, 0, 0)
      .setOption('title', "Total hour split in 2020");
   var blob = chartBuilder.build().getBlob();
  destSheet.insertImage(blob, 1, 1); 
}
```