# Grabbing a Chart as image via JS script and Google Sheets API?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, discord, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a Discord Bot that will grab a specified chart from a Google Sheet and send the chart to the server. The sheet on hand will only ever have one chart at a time, so I've been able to find the correct `chartId` as follows:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.get({
    spreadsheetId: 'MYSPREADSHEETID'
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    var id = res.data.sheets[0].charts[0].chartId;
});
```

However, I cannot find out how to export the corresponding chart as an image, or find a unique URL to the chart, or even recreate the chart using the existing data. I'm using discord.js and Google Sheets API v4.

Comment: Unfortunately,at the moment of this comment it isn't possible to get a chart as an image or get its url using Sheets API.However, there are some workrounds.The first one is offered in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#read_chart_data) which will return a sheet object with the chart.You could also move the chart in the UI to its own sheet so that it has a specific sheet assigned to it.

Comment: The second is to publish the Chart as [specified here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1047436?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) which lets you get a link or its embedding. You could also use Apps Script to deploy it as a web App and from there get its Blob object to generate the image as shown in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60266976/12835757). **Let me know if these workarounds suit your case or if you would be looking for something else**.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Thanks so much! Publishing the chart as an image and using that link worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the moment of this post, unfortunately it is not possible to retrieve a chart as an image or get its specifc URL with Sheets API. Here I present three workarounds when we encounter the issue of trying to retrieve the image of a chart in a spreadsheet.

### Workaround 1

If your main intention is to get the chart data to then use it somewhere else or create a data [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob) with it for other Google Applications, you can use the API method `GET` requesting only the desired fields (in our case, the chart objects) as shown in [this example of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#read_chart_data).

### Workaround 2

If what you need is to easily access this chart image with a simple link, you could publish your chart following [these steps shown in the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1047436?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). This can generate either a **link** or an **embed** for your website that you can easily share and use.

### Workaround 3

You can use Apps Script to create a Web App and using the API method in the first workaround generate a Blob from the chart object and use it to be inserted as an image either in another sheet or in a HTML page. In [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60266976/12835757) you can see an exmple of the implementation of this workaround.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)